# iPhoto 10 : is there still a way to subscribe to rss feed?

Tags: photos.app, rss

I thought there was a menu entry in iPhoto to subscribe to RSS feeds.

I can't find it anymore. Is there still a way to do so in iPhoto 10 ?

Comment: Does pressing Command-key + U work?

Comment: Sadly, no... I guess the functionality disappeared, but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been removed. There's no mention of it that I can find in Apple's support documentation or iPhoto help (⌘?) and the only reference to subscribing that I can find is subscribing to a Shared Photo Stream.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphoto.html

Comment: I added a feature request. Without any great hope, but who knows ? Looks like RSS is a technology for dinosaurs.